# Capturing the standard output in Gradle 0.8 builds

Tags: groovy, gradle

Say I have src/test/groovy/MyTest.groovy:

```
class MyTest extends GroovyTestCase {
  void testDummy() {
    println 'DUMMY'
  }
}
```

And there is nothing special with my build.gradle:

```
usePlugin 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    groovy group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy', version: '1.7.5'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.7'
}
```

Why don't I get *DUMMY* printed at the standard output when I run `gradle test` in the command line? Am I missing something?

```
~$ gradle test
:compileJava
:compileGroovy
:processResources
:classes
:compileTestJava
:compileTestGroovy
:processTestResources
:testClasses
:test

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 5.372 secs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look in build/reports/test-result

Comment: Thanks, but actually I'd like to have it printed on the standard output instead. I'm wondering if it's configurable.